# How do you copy a 2 column array into a Mat in opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, opencv

I attempted it using [matFromArray](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html) but it does not produce a 2 column Mat with the same data.

```
let matTest = cv.matFromArray(3, 2, cv.CV_32FC2, [
                 [474.71202312578005, 43.10697795776387], 
                 [453.70202392070125, 45.16493777776367], 
                 [773.76202002578125, 40.60593795888867]
              ]);
console.log(matTest);
```

Produces this:

```
Mat {$$: {…}}
    cols: 2
    data: Uint8Array(48)    
    data8S: Int8Array(48)
    data16S: Int16Array(24)
    data16U: Uint16Array(24)
    data32F: Float32Array(12)
        0: NaN
        1: NaN
        2: NaN
        3: 0
        4: 1.3816650396969778e-37
        5: 0
        6: 3.882013772602726e-37
        7: 0
        8: 1.373597596282044e-37
        9: 0
        10: 3.849743998942992e-37
        11: 0
        buffer: ArrayBuffer(134217728)
        byteLength: 48
        byteOffset: 17563200
        length: 12
        Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
    __proto__: TypedArray   
    data32S: Int32Array(12)
    data64F: Float64Array(6)
    matSize: Array(2)
    rows: 3
    step: Array(2)
        0: 16
        1: 8
        length: 2
```

I think (but not positive) all that matFromArray() does is this:

```
var matTest = new cv.Mat(array2copy.rows,array2copy.cols,cv.CV_32FC2);
matTest.data32F.set(array2copy);
```

does **[TypedArray.prototype.set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set)** support 2 column arrays?  can't tell from docs.

is there a better way to copy this data into the Mat using Javascript in OpenCV?

possibly by using: matTest.floatAt(row,column) =